# помогите с хеадером

Tags: php, javascript, css

не могу приклеить хеадер к верху сайта, уже и скриптом пробовал и чисто css, http://testslab.ru/, сейчас не на всю ширину, нужно растянуть на всю, width: 100%; не помогает

Comment: position: fixed

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы про то, что шапка отступила от верха, то у Вас вся шапка в теге `<div class="wrapper">`, у которого есть отступ сверху `margin-top: 30px;`. Либо уберите отступ (74 строка), либо, если где-то этот margin нужен, перепишите шапку.

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper{
    margin-top: 80px;
}
.header{
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: зачем translate? просто `left: 0, right: 0` и содержимое хедера обернуть в центрирующий контейнер. translate может поплыть в некоторых браузерах на 0.5px

Comment: Согласен @ Artem Gorlachev, даже не в некоторых браузерах, а если они поймают ширину хххх.5px

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, потому что translate работает для неизвестной ширины.